# (Mysql) merging two tables by datetime range

Tags: mysql, join, dataframe

There are two tables and the first one has start & end date.

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id |    start   |     end    | 
+----+------------+------------+
|  a | 2016-07-10 | 2016-07-12 |
|  a | 2016-07-12 | 2016-07-18 |
|  a | 2016-07-20 | 2016-07-24 |
|  b | 2016-07-11 | 2016-07-15 |
|  b | 2016-07-17 | 2016-07-20 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

what i want to join is the table below.

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id |    count   |    pno     |     date   | 
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  a |     1      |     1      | 2016-07-12 |
|  a |     1      |     1      | 2016-07-15 |
|  a |     0      |     1      | 2016-07-16 |
|  a |     1      |     1      | 2016-07-17 |
|  b |     0      |     1      | 2016-07-12 |
|  b |     1      |     1      | 2016-07-13 |
|  b |     1      |     1      | 2016-07-14 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

And the result i want to get is

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| id |    start   |     end    |  per_pno   |  per_count |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  a | 2016-07-10 | 2016-07-12 |      1     |      1     |
|  a | 2016-07-12 | 2016-07-18 |      3     |      2     |
|  a | 2016-07-20 | 2016-07-24 |      0     |      0     |
|  b | 2016-07-11 | 2016-07-15 |      3     |      2     |
|  b | 2016-07-17 | 2016-07-20 |      0     |      0     |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

as you can see count, pno sumed by each period between start & end date and 'id' condition...

It seemed very dificult to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the two tables on the condition that a date from the second table lie in between the range of a given record in the first table, where the `id` matches in both tables.  Then, aggregate over each row in the first table to get the totals.  Note that the join condition is slightly tricky, because your ranges can end and start on the same date.  Hence, the join condition makes certain that we do not double count days.

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.start,
    t1.end,
    COALESCE(SUM(t2.pno), 0)   AS per_pno,
    COALESCE(SUM(t2.count), 0) AS per_count
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND
       t2.date > t1.start AND t2.date <= t1.end
GROUP BY
    t1.id, t1.start, t1.end
ORDER BY
    t1.id, t1.start;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Use This Query

```
SELECT tbl1.start1 as start1, tbl1.end1 as end1, sum(tbl2.count1) as countq, sum(tbl2.pno) as pno FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON (tbl2.date1 BETWEEN tbl1.start1 AND tbl1.end1) WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY tbl1.id
```